# Can not run syncdb with Django and mongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I get `django-nonrel`, `djangotoolbox` and `mongodbengine` from github, and the `setting.py` is as following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'admin',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
} 

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ptl.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/Users/bxshi/PycharmProjects/ptl/templates',)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
)
```

Except that `settings.py`, I do not have any other `.py` file in my project.

The error I got is that:

```
BaoxuShis-MacBook:ptl bxshi$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 109, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 190, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py", line 11, in update_contenttypes
    content_types = list(ContentType.objects.filter(app_label=app.__name__.split('.')[-2]))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 84, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 275, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 335, in results_iter
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 430, in build_query
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py", line 160, in add_filters
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py", line 168, in add_filters
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

I find something related to this error about mongodbengine, a thread on BBS talk about that, but it says this is already fixed.

Comment: Do you have a plain installation of django-nonrel or are you using e.g. buildout or virtualenv? From the traceback it seems that the django is being used from `/Library/...` while djangotoolbox and django-mongodb-engine are being used from `build/...`.

Comment: I just got these sources(Django Djangotoolbox, etc.) from github and then use `sudo python setup.py install` to install that. No `virutalenv` used. The thing is `Django1.4` installed into the path where I install `python`, others are installed to `/build/...`

Comment: If you used the Django1.4 repo from github, this might not work. Clone the django-nonrel repo. See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-non-relational/Hj6hmX_2KIA/discussion for further discussion about this.

Comment: django-nonrel is also installed. I delete django and reinstall django-norel also have this problem.

Comment: why you need syncdb? add one user only

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the official installation instructions on https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

Comment: official guide's django-nonrel is out of date. It could cause some problems about insert in tuple. So I find the newer one on github. I'll try use virtualenv see if I can solve it.

Comment: Still got that problem. Maybe I'll try to use a linux as my development server.

Comment: they aren't out of date. It should work perfectly well if you follow the instructions I linked.

Comment: I upload my project on dotcloud. and that works fine. But with instructions provided on django-mongodb, it really cause some problems.

Comment: They are actually out of date, since django-nonrel has long moved to github. I just tried to use these instructions and got infinite recursion exception (and initially I had the same problem as stated in the original question)